# Azure static website does not return 404.html page

Tags: azure

I created an Azure static website following [Microsoft's tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host). Everything works, except that Azure doesn't return the `404.html` page for HTTP 404 requests.

---

My static website settings:

[image: Azure static website settings]

---

When I navigate to a page that doesn't exist, these are the headers Azure returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 The requested content does not exist.
Content-Length: 1214
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Windows-Azure-Web/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-error-code: WebContentNotFound
x-ms-request-id: 2680e62d-a01e-002a-7d48-de2087000000
x-ms-version: 2018-03-28
Date: Sat, 08 Feb 2020 06:25:27 GMT
```

Those headers are correct. But here's what shows in the browser:

[image: funny characters returned by Azure]

---

I've verified that my `404.html` page works fine by navigating directly to that page:

[image: 404 page works in browser]

If I use the 'Storage Explorer' I can also see that my `404.html` file is in `$web`:

[image: 404.html is in Azure Blob storage]

Yet Azure doesn't return that page for HTTP 404 errors.

Things I tried:

- Different browsers (Firefox and Chrome). Got the same result.
- Emptied browser cache.
- Re-uploaded the 404.html page.
- Searched online for people with the same problem (didn't found any).
- Verified my static website settings against several online tutorials. It seems my settings are correct.

---

**Update:** Following Biren's suggestion I set the `$web` container to the 'Container' access level. After re-uploading my files the issue still remains. But the text in the browser looks different now:

[image: changed text in browser]

These are the returned HTTP headers for files not in the blob (unchanged from earlier and still proper 404 from what I can tell):

```
HTTP/1.1 404 The requested content does not exist.
Content-Length: 966
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Windows-Azure-Web/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
x-ms-error-code: WebContentNotFound
x-ms-request-id: 6bfc762c-b01e-0026-1113-dfb78f000000
x-ms-version: 2018-03-28
Date: Sun, 09 Feb 2020 06:38:03 GMT
```

Comment: check blob container if it's public access

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I changed the access level to 'Container', which should give the most permissions as possible. Unfortunately the issue remains. The text I see in the browser is a little different though, I'll update the question with a new image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself today. The software I use to upload my website by default Gzips every HTML file. This is pretty standard and good behaviour. Unfortunately, Azure Blob Storage 404 pages **do not** support Gzip encoding.

This limitation isn't documented, although there's a feedback request for Gzip encoding of 404 pages [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/37989187-gzip-encoding-for-404-document-in-static-website-h).

So the solution is simple: when uploading the static website, Gzip all HTML pages except `404.html`. As soon as I did that, my strange text on 404 pages disappeared and everything works fine now.